# “Overload” function template based on function object operator() signature in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, overloading, c++98

I want to make a template function that takes a function and a vector and uses the function to map that vector to another vector that will be returned by the function template.

If the function taken as an argument is a free function, it may have one of two signatures.

```
// T is the parameter of the function template
T sig1(const T x);
T sig2(const T x, const std::vector<T>& v);
```

It may also be a function object in which `operator()` would behave like the free functions. Use of the function template for any of the 4 possibilities should be transparent.

```
std::vector<int> v;
// ... fill v somehow ...

// foo is either free function or function object instance
const std::vector<int> a = map_vec(foo, v);
```

I asked how to do this for C++11 and got a great answer from 0x499602D2.

["Overload" function template based on function object operator() signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321959/overload-function-template-based-on-function-object-operator-signature)

0x499602D2's answer makes use of the fact that these are two distinct template signatures in C++11:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
auto map_vec(F&& fnc, const std::vector<T>& source)
    -> decltype(void(fnc(std::declval<T>())), std::vector<T>{});

template<typename F, typename T>
auto map_vec(F&& fnc, const std::vector<T>& source)
    -> decltype(void(fnc(std::declval<T>(), source)), std::vector<T>{});
```

I would also like to know how to solve this in C++98.

Here is my effort so far. I have a SFINAE struct that can determine if a function objects takes two args. I don't know how to get this working for both function objects and free functions. Either I need to change the SFINAE struct to work on both function objects and free functions or I need to use overloading to route function objects and free functions separately.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1471088cbc3b8544

Comment: Solving this for C++98 indicates an older compiler version. The problem is that older compiler versions often merely support expression SFINAE - partly because name mangling wasn't supporting that stuff a couple of years ago. Try to put the expression into a partial specialization template argument list to avoid at least that.

Comment: I just mean the C++98 standard, not the compilers of the era. g++ 4.9 with -std=c++98 is fine.

Comment: So what exactly is the point of putting g++ 4.9 in that mode? I.e. what's the practical relevance of creating a solution that only works for compiler versions which support a newer standard (with which we could compose a better solution)?

Comment: You can think of C++98 and C++11 as separate but related languages. The job may call for one or the other but you (almost) always want the implementation to be up to date and as correct as possible.

Comment: Nonsense. C++11 is an *improved* version of C++98. If you can use it, *do so*.

Comment: And what would you say of C? Also obsolete? In all seriousness though, C++11 does introduce breaking changes and so is not strictly "C++98 and more". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11. A practical use of C++98 with modern compilers is interfacing with legacy code. This is really off topic though. Maybe you should open a question on Programmers SE?

Comment: You're right - otherwise this comment discussion would digress too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
template <std::size_t, typename T = void> struct ignore_value {typedef T type;};

template <typename T>
T& declval();

template<typename F, typename T>
typename ignore_value<sizeof(declval<F>()(declval<T const>())),
       std::vector<T> >::type map_vec(F fnc, const std::vector<T>& source);

template<typename F, typename T>
typename ignore_value<sizeof(declval<F>()
                         (declval<T const>(), declval<const std::vector<T> >())),
       std::vector<T> >::type map_vec(F fnc, const std::vector<T>& source);
```

It [**works with the same Demo that 0x499602D2 used**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d578d4dc54e4c8be), with both GCC and Clang in C++98 mode.

Comment: Could you briefly explain the `declval` part?

Comment: I think I get `declval<F>` but why is it used on `T` and `std::vector` too?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Because we don't want to a) Unnecessarily require a default constructor for `T`, b) Don't want to restrict our set of accepted `F`'s to ones that can accept a temporary `vector` as the second argument.

Comment: Are you sure about b? If I change `declval<const std::vector<T> >()` to `std::vector<T>()` all seems well. I tried with functions that take as value, const value, and const ref and they all compiled.

Comment: @Praxeolitic [Convoluted counterexample for C++98](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/991e6b79b14731e5). Or for C++11 (in case the code might be ported): A parameter of a class type that has two non-`explicit` constructors: One that has a parameter of type const lvalue reference to `vector<>`, and one that is deleted and has a parameter of type rvalue reference to `vector<>`. [Second demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47018959a91b36ae).