# How can I overload a function with a callable object as a parameter based on the object's call signature?

Tags: templates, overloading, c++98, method-signature, callable-object

For example, given the following code

```
class A {
 public:
    double operator()(double foo) {
        return foo;
    }
};

class B {
 public:
    double operator()(double foo, int bar) {
        return foo + bar;
    }
};
```

I want to write two versions of `fun`, one that works with objects with A's signature and another one that works with objects with B's signature:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
T fun(F f, T t) {
    return f(t);
}

template <typename F, typename T>
T fun(F f, T t) {
    return f(t, 2);
}
```

And I expect this behavior

```
A a();
B b();
fun(a, 4.0);  // I want this to be 4.0
fun(b, 4.0);  // I want this to be 6.0
```

Of course the previous example throws a template redefinition error at compile time.

If B is a function instead, I can rewrite `fun` to be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T fun(T (f)(T, int), T t) {
    return f(t, 2);
}
```

But I want `fun` to work with both, functions and callable objects. Using `std::bind` or `std::function` maybe would solve the problem, but I'm using C++98 and those were introduced in C++11.

Comment: It is not really possible. A single callable object can have more than one signature (e.g. an overloaded `operator()`).

Comment: Something similar is possible in C++>=11 but 98 seems too weak.

Comment: I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324124/overload-function-template-based-on-function-object-operator-signature-in-c?rq=1) was accomplishing something similar, but I found the code too confusing.

@n.m. I don't really see how a callable object having more than one signature can affect the template deduction.

Comment: The linked answer is based on sizeof(value-returned-by-call) which breaks down when the target function returns void. But if this isn't important to you it's possible to use this approach.

Comment: In some of my cases, the function returns `void` so no dice.

Comment: Wait I think I have a way, hold on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324124/overload-function-template-based-on-function-object-operator-signature-in-c?rq=1) to accommodate void-returning functions. The solution is simply to use `sizeof(possibly-void-expression, 1)`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

// like std::declval in c++11
template <typename T>
T& decl_val();

// just use the type and ignore the value. 
template <std::size_t, typename T = void> 
struct ignore_value {typedef T type;};

// This is basic expression-based SFINAE.
// If the expression inside sizeof() is invalid, substitution fails.
// The expression, when valid, is always of type int, 
// thanks to the comma operator.
// The expression is valid if an F is callable with specified parameters. 
template <class F>
typename ignore_value<sizeof(decl_val<F>()(1),1), void>::type
call(F f)
{
    f(1);
}

// Same, with different parameters passed to an F.
template <class F>
typename ignore_value<sizeof(decl_val<F>()(1,1),1), void>::type
call(F f)
{
    f(1, 2);
}

void func1(int) { std::cout << "func1\n"; }
void func2(int,int) { std::cout << "func2\n"; }

struct A
{
    void operator()(int){ std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B
{
    void operator()(int, int){ std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C
{
    void operator()(int){ std::cout << "C1\n"; }
    void operator()(int, int){ std::cout << "C2\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    call(func1);
    call(func2);
    call(A());
    call(B());
    // call(C()); // ambiguous
}
```

Checked with gcc and clang in c++98 mode.

Comment: This is even more than what I've asked for! Thank you so much!